# Move number away from n in C++

Tags: c++

I am looking for a simple way to increment/decrement a number away from n, without using if statements, or creating a function. Here is an example:

```
Increment x from 9 to 10, n is 6
Decrement x from 3 to 2, n is 6
```

An obvious way to do this is with if statements, but that seems like too much code in my opinion. Here is a function that I could imagine using:

```
x += 1 * GetSign(6, 9) //GetSign(A, B) returns 1 or -1 depending on what would
```

Be necessary to move farther away from 6. The made up function above would look something like:

```
 int GetSign(A, B)
{ 
   if( A < B) return -1; 
   else return 1;
}
```

Comment: Return type of `GetSign()` is void, how could you return an integer from that function?

Comment: I feel like you're trying to solve some math problem and going about it the complete wrong way.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I was just providing an example function, and my understanding of C++ is at a beginner level at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
int A = 6;
int B = 9;
x += (A < B) ? (-1) : (1);
```